# pouchDB retrieve allDocs original query

Tags: pouchdb

I am attempting to load a local PouchDB with results from a website. Once the results are loaded locally, I don't want to bother with downloading them again.

To avoid this, I get a list of files that exist, and then test to see if I've loaded it in the past before fetching it.

```
function DownloadFile($fname){
        $query = {
            include_docs: false,
            attachments: false,
            startkey: ['run',$fname].join(','),
            endkey: ['run',$fname,'\uffff'].join(',')
        };
        db.allDocs($query).then(function (result) {
            if ( result.rows.length !== 0 ) return;
            $url = './runDb/' + $fname + '/results.xml';
            $.ajax({
                url: $url,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml",
                async: true,
                success: function (results,status,xhr) {
                    app.ParseResults($fname,results)
                }
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

The problem I am having is that by the time `DownloadFile` get's called 100 times and the `allDocs` query finally returns something, I no longer know what the original query that returned no results.

Is there a way in PouchDb to determine the query parameters that were used to produce a given result set?

*EDIT*: While I really like the accepted answer, it appears this was a dumb question. Experimentation (in the browser) indicates that `$query` and `$fname` will contain the correctly scoped value for the particular call that initiated `allDocs` call.

In other words, I don't really need to do anything, it just works. Obviously, this is highly dependant on the JS implementation, therefore the accepted answer is better because it is explicit about what is desired.

Comment: I am often amazed at the dark wizardry that is javascript variable scoping, and the plethora of weird scenarios it just handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to PouchDB, it is a solution that can be used for all sorts of similar cases.

The answer below assumes you have a valid `Promise` object hanging around.

```
function DownloadFile($fname){
  $query = {
      include_docs: false,
      attachments: false,
      startkey: ['run',$fname].join(','),
      endkey: ['run',$fname,'\uffff'].join(',')
  };
  return Promise.all([
    $query,
    db.allDocs($query),
  ]).then(function (resp) {

    // you'll have your query right here.
    var $query = resp[0]
    var result = resp[1]

    if ( result.rows.length !== 0 ) return;
    $url = './runDb/' + $fname + '/results.xml';
    $.ajax({
      url: $url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "xml",
      contentType: "text/xml",
      async: true,
      success: function (results,status,xhr) {
        app.ParseResults($fname,results)
      }
    });
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```